# Trace event message ordering using erlang:trace_delivered/1

Tags: erlang, trace

I am trying to understand the exact semantics of `erlang:trace_delivered/1` in order to determine whether this function can be suitably used to solve a problem I am currently facing. The problem is as follows.

Suppose there is a tracee process `X`, a tracer `Y` tracing `X`, and a third process, `Z`. Tracer `Y` is initially tracing `X`. Process `Z` is tasked with the responsibility of stopping `Y` from tracing `X` by calling `erlang:trace(X, false)`. This call is **arbitrarily** effected by `Z` whilst `X` is running. Thereafter, `Z` is also to issue a special message `stopped` to tracer `Y` which signals to `Y` that `Z` has indeed stopped `Y` from tracing `X`.

I would like to guarantee that the special `stopped` message is delivered to `Y`'s mailbox **after** all other trace messages have been delivered to `Y`. To my knowledge, Erlang does not guarantee the ordering of messages sent by different processes to a single process. Concretely in my case this means that tracer `Y` can, for instance, receive the `stopped` issued by `Z` **before** the trace event messages due to tracee `X`. I read about `erlang:trace_delivered/1`, and was planning to address my problem using the following code inside the implementation of `Z`:

```
...
erlang:trace(X, false),
Ref = erlang:trace_delivered(X),
receive
  {trace_delivered, X, Ref} ->
    Y ! stopped
end.
...
```

A somewhat similar example is provided in the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace_delivered-1) (quoted below):

> Example: Process `A` is Tracee, port `B` is tracer, and process `C` is the port owner of `B`. `C` wants to close `B` when `A` exits. To ensure that the trace is not truncated, `C` can call `erlang:trace_delivered(A)` when `A` exits, and wait for message `{trace_delivered, A, Ref}` before closing `B`.

My example differs from the one in the docs in these two respects:

1. Process `C` knows the exact point of execution of `A` **prior** to invoking `erlang:trace_delivered(A)`; in my case, I do not know the point `X` is in when `erlang:trace_delivered(X)` is invoked by `Z`.
2. By contrast to process `C`, my process `Z` switches off tracing on `X` before invoking `erlang:trace_delivered(X)`.

---

What are the semantics of `erlang:trace_delivered/1` in this case?

1. Does it still guarantee that `{trace_delivered, X, Ref}` is received by process `Z` **after all** trace messages have been delivered to tracer `Y`?
2. And does `erlang:trace_delivered/1` automatically keep track of the point at which the execution of tracee `X` is at to be able to provide the aforementioned guarantee?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the ordering of messages. If process `A` sends multiple messages to process `B` they will be guaranteed to arrive in order. If `A` sends multiple messages to processes `B` and `C` the message order will only be guaranteed per-process. So for example:

- `A` sends `B` message 1
- `A` sends `C` message 2
- `A` sends `B` message 3
- `A` sends `C` message 4

The only guarantees in this scenario is that `B` will receive message 1 before message 3, and `C` will receive  message 2 before message 4.

To answer your questions:

1. No, if `erlang:trace_delivered/1` is invoked prior to other trace events being generated those messages will arrive later. The docs only guarantee that prior trace messages are delivered prior to `{trace_delivered, ...}`:

   > When it is guaranteed that all trace messages are delivered to the tracer up to the point that Tracee reached at the time of the call to erlang:trace_delivered(Tracee), then a {trace_delivered, Tracee, Ref} message is sent to the caller of erlang:trace_delivered(Tracee) .
2. The guarantees around `erlang:trace_delivered/1` always hold true. But it doesn't guarantee that `{trace_delivered, ...}` will always be the last message.